# Looper not mocked ViewModel MockitoJUnitRunner

Tags: android, unit-testing, viewmodel, junit4, android-architecture-components

I can't find a solution that will help me test my `ViewModel`s. I keep reading that it's enough to add rule :

```
 @get:Rule
 var rule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

but I keep getting :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
```

My test class looks like this now :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MainActivityViewModelTest {

@get:Rule
val taskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

val weatherProviderMock = mock<WeatherProvider>()
val sut = MainActivityViewModel(weatherProviderMock, mock(), mock(),     mock())

    @Test
    fun shouldPass() {
        assertTrue(true)
    }
}
```

I also have the following in my app build.gradle:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.22.0'
testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.9.1'
testImplementation 'com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.6.0'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.22.0'
```

Any help much appreciated.

***@Chris***

Can you please tell me if there's anything wrong with the code below (as per your proposed solutions):

```
lateinit var sut: SummaryViewModel
@get:Rule
val rule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

@Before
fun setUp() {
    sut = SummaryViewModel(calculatorMock, mock(), mock(), mock(), providerMock, mock())
}

@Test
fun `live data test`() {
    val someLiveData = sut.someLiveDataValue
    assertThat(true).isTrue()
}
```

Comment: What does your MainActivityViewModel do in it's constructor?

Comment: @Chris, I've made some operations on LiveData in the constructor. I still don't know what the issue with this is, but apparently moving this out from constructor made the test to pass and looper to be mocked. One more thing worth mentioning here is that the `ViewModel` is in Java and tests are kotlin, not sure how could that affect the mocking but maybe? Any idea?

Comment: If your ViewModel is interacting with LiveData in its constructor you'll need to delay the creation of your ViewModel until the rule has been executed. You could for example declare the ViewModel as a lateinit property and use the @Before annotation to create it in a setup method with any configured mocks.

Comment: @Chris - I've posted a solution based on your comment, would you please take a look it's in the updated question at the bottom.

Comment: Do you still get the looper issue?

Comment: @Chris - your solutions works, but isn't `@Before` called before every `@Test` method? Btw -> add an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setValue and postValue on MutableLiveData in UnitTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988310/setvalue-and-postvalue-on-mutablelivedata-in-unittest)

Answer (score 0):

You could lazily initialize the `ViewModel` using [Kotlin delegates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy):

```
    val viewModel by lazy { 
        MainActivityViewModel(weatherProviderMock, mock(), mock()...)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case none of the solutions worked alike in my case, if you are using a later version of Gradle and you are using androix, make sure you import from **androix** in your build gradle.

> implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$version'

instead of

> implementation 'android.arch.core:core-testing:$version'