# Unit Test Fails : java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked

Tags: java, android, kotlin, junit, retrofit2

Am having a challenge, where my test passes when I run it alone but fails when I run all the tests, it shows me this error message :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper
>   not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
>
> at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java)     at
>   retrofit2.Platform$Android$MainThreadExecutor.(Platform.java:172)
>     at
>   retrofit2.Platform$Android.defaultCallbackExecutor(Platform.java:145)
>     at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.build(Retrofit.java:585)  at
>   com.andela.mrm.notifications.SlackService.getApi(SlackService.kt:26)
>     at
>   com.andela.mrm.notifications.SlackServiceTest.getAPI(SlackServiceTest.kt:12)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)  at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)    at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Below is the Retrofit instance I want to test :

```
class SlackService {

    private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

    /**
     * This method creates a new instance of the API interface.
     *
     * @return The API interface
     */
    val api: SlackApi
        get() {
            val baseURL = "https://hooks.slack.com/"
            val client = ApiService.getOkHttpClient()
            if (retrofit == null) {
                retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(baseURL)
                        .client(client)
                        .build()
            }
            return retrofit!!.create(SlackApi::class.java)
        }
}
```

And then, this is a test for the Retrofit Instance :

```
class SlackServiceTest {

    @Test
    fun getAPI() {
        val slackService = SlackService()
        assertNotNull(slackService.api)
    }
}
```

I managed to see some similar [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356314/android-rxjava-2-junit-test-getmainlooper-in-android-os-looper-not-mocked-runt) via here but they are related with RxJava , and am not using it, how can I be helped ?

Thanks

Comment: Show code with other tests.

Comment: This error happens when you try to execute asynchronous task in your test.

Comment: There are lots of tests , I cant post them here @ArslanShoukat

Comment: Yes , it happens when youy try to execute asynchronous task in your task.

Comment: Could you post at least one another test that you have so we can try out and give you reasonable answer?

Answer (score 6):

Adding this fixed the issue for me.

```
android {
  // ...
  testOptions { 
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by Liz here and it worked for me. It was a silly mistake. Glad to find a solution after a long trials. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69109928

Pasting the solution for easy reference

In case none of the solutions worked alike in my case, if you are using a later version of Gradle and you are using androix, make sure you import from androix in your build gradle.

implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$version'

instead of

implementation 'android.arch.core:core-testing:$version'

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I finally got the answer, it's in the link below:
[Answer](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Method-...-not-mocked.-)

Comment: Thank you so much man. It finally works. I have been searching for 40 minutes.

Comment: @IdrisStack The site you mentioned here is not available anymore

Comment: This is why we put a full answer here, to avoid losing information when sites go offline